# D3 popups size on a Zoom in World Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

On my D3 world map, i have a parent svg:g group called "main" which have two svg:g element, one for countries and another for popups.

I draw countries path under svg:g element called "countries". and under svg:g called "popups", i draw popups nodes using d3 force layout which show multiple callouts as rectangles.

Clicking on any country will to zoom that country to screen size. [zoom to bounding box, Mike bostok](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541). if am applying zoom on svg:g "countries" as i dont want the popups to zoom as they will get extra big.

Since Boundingbox for smaller country will have large scale and large countries will have small scale values.

Now how should i calculate the translate and scale for the Svg:g "popups", so that the popups rectangle size and fonts remain same.

Answer (score 1):

It worked like a charm by using a formula:
[position after zoom has been applied ] * (1 - scalePopup).
See below for how to calculate the variable scalePopup

```
  var bounds = path.bounds(d),
        dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
        dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
        x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
        y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2;

    var scale = countryZoomScale(Math.max(dx, dy)) / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
        translate = [width / 1.5 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

    var scalePopup = map.zoomFactor / scale;
    var popupLayer = d3.select('.popupLayer');
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);

    popupLayer.attr("transform", "translate(" + centroid[0] * (1 -      scalePopup) + "," + centroid[1] * (1 - scalePopup) + ")scale(" + scalePopup + ")");
```